# Product alerts cron warnings

Tags: magento-2.1, error, cron

Very recently I had to perform a minor upgrade on an extension (eBizmarts Mailchimp) in my Magento 2.1.7 installation. It went smoothly, as usual, even though it is terrifying to do this for fear of Magento completely breaking!

Anyway, after going through all the usual steps, and cleaning caches, etc, the site was returned to LIVE status, and all appeared to be normal.
My steps are as follows:
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_GB
bin/magento indexer:reindex
bin/magento cache:clean
bin/magento cache:flush
Reapply permissions

That night, and every night since, I get an email at 1:20am with these contents:

> Product alerts cron warnings
>
> Warning: getimagesize(): Filename cannot be empty in /var/www/vhosts/website/htdocs/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product/Image.php on line 922
>
> Warning: getimagesize(): Filename cannot be empty in /var/www/vhosts/website/htdocs/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product/Image.php on line 922
>
> Warning: getimagesize(): Filename cannot be empty in
>   /var/www/vhosts/website/htdocs/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product/Image.php on line 922

And so it continues, exactly the same for another 91 lines.

I do not see any corresponding error in any log files.

I can only imagine that something is perhaps cached on the server somewhere (in Magento) causing this, but it isn't actually causing an error? Maybe it is but I don't know about it.

Has anyone come across this before and knows what the issue is, and more importantly, how to fix it?

I am able to manually run cron on the server without any errors. When I use the command:

> bin/magento cron:run

I get the following message back:

> Ran jobs by schedule.

The error did not happen before the last update as mentioned above, and any products that have been added since the update have all got perfectly working images against them.

Could it be an unseen rogue image on a new item maybe?
Or maybe 94 new items (one for each entry in this email)?

How do I debug this with no apparently useful info beyond this email?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a 2.1.7 available at the moment, but:

1. You could *temporarily* edit the core to output a more precise error message, maybe with a SKU
2. if you only do `bin/magento cron:run` when the conjob in question (product alerts) is not scheduled, it will not be executed and you won't be able to see the error messages. `n98-magerun2` has a nice command `sys:cron:run` that actually lets you run a job by code. If you run `php n98-magerun2.phar sys:cron:run catalog_product_alert` from your command line, you could also be able to reproduce the error on your development machine
3. In my Magento (v2.1.8), there's a comment in line 922, but some placeholder-functionality using `getimagesize()` is right below. So you might want to check this setting first, to see if it is configured correctly

Comment: Thanks for this useful response! Appreciated!! I am keen to try out n98-magerun2, but having searched through tons of documentation about it, I cannot find out if it is a server based installation, or a magento based installation? I think it is server based, but I cannot find a definitive answer to this, and I am worried about installing it and breaking my Magento!

Comment: You don't install it. It's a PHAR file, similar to Java's JAR files. You simply download it, log into your server with SSH (or use your local terminal) and execute it using PHP. Complete guide here: https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun#download-and-install-phar-file and yes, that's it. It does not interfere with your Magento installation. A normal user that requests the front- oder backend will have no contact with n98-magerun

Comment: Oh, the link is for Magento 1. Here is an update: https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun2#download-and-install-phar-file

Comment: Thanks again for the help. Making more sense to me right now :-) Time to have a play with n98-magerun2!